# How to get data through $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "wordtyping_sql.php",
    data: "id=" + id + "&formname=" + formname,
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
});
```

`msg` that contains three lines from `wordtyping_sql.php` which are:

```
echo "one"; 
echo "two"; 
echo "three";
```

How do I get this data separately?

Answer (score 5):

What you'll want to do is have your PHP code echo out some JSON data. Then you'll be able to access any one of the variables you wish.

In `wordtyping_sql.php` -

```
$data = array(
  'one' => 1,
  'two' => 2,
  'three' => 3
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Now in your jQuery, you'll want to specify that your AJAX call is expecting a JSON in return -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "wordtyping_sql.php",
    data: "id=" + id + "&formname=" + formname,
    dataType : 'json', // <------------------ this line was added
    success: function(response){
        alert( response.one );
        alert( response.two );
        alert( response.three );
    }
});
```

Check out the [relevant documentation pages for jQuery's AJAX method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Specifically the `dataType` parameter -

> **dataType** -  The type of data that you're expecting back from the
>   server...

Comment: thanks a lot, but one thing strange happened when I add dataType : 'json', I found the alert() part didn't work, nothing comes out. but if I comment it, it worked again. Do you know the reason?

Comment: Ok, it works now, I think I wasn't working for I didn't add json_encode.

Comment: but one more important question: why I failed to convert reponse.one to id? please see the code below: var id=80; $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "wordtyping_sql.php",
    data: "id=" + id + "&formname=" + formname,
    dataType : 'json', // <------------------ this line was added
    success: function(response){
        id = response.one;
    }
});alert(id); why do I see the same value 80 intead of the new value of response.one?

Comment: Well that is `wordtyping_sql.php` returning?

Comment: it just return a number. But anyway, I've solved the problem.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Return the data as a JSON string. jQuery will parse it and turn it into an object you can work with.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "wordtyping_sql.php",
    data: "id=" + id + "&formname=" + formname,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg);
    }
});
```

wordtyping_sql.php

```
echo '["one","two","three"]';
```

Then inside of your successhandler you can access the data as msg[0], msg[1]. etc.

Comment: Why are you building a JavaScript array manually? What's wrong with `json_encode()`?

Comment: Your script would also cause syntax errors if any element of the "array" contained quotation characters...

Comment: It was just an example, I'm not actually advocating statically building an array like that. I am showing him what the data would look like when it was returned.

Comment: Anyway, I also have a very disturbing problem for me. I don't if you ever developed online dictionary before, but I want to achieve one function which is when I type in one English word, and the user can get lots of example sentences from the internet. Noted, the sentences are provided by some kind of engine, but I just couldn't figure out how to do that, is anyone of you have idea?